# VSTS build on clean due to dotnet version

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My VSTS build has started to fail recently when doing a `clean` and it looks like it is something to do with the dotnet version that it's running. If I do a `dotnet --version` I get the following output:

2018-05-31T16:40:51.0191791Z 2.1.300-rc1-008673

Why is the build agent running a RC version of the dotnet? How can I fix this to a released version?

Looking around at the scripts for building the images for the agents I came across this change which is suppose to stop installing preview/rc version - https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/commit/e9c0aec89ad797d1985a76ab262349b943b02c34 but the agent that is getting built at the moment for me is has rc version?

Here are the error logs from VSTS when we hit out clean stage that runs `dotnet clean`

```
2018-06-01T10:35:05.2388624Z ========================================
2018-06-01T10:35:05.2389045Z Clean
2018-06-01T10:35:05.2389205Z ========================================
2018-06-01T10:35:05.2389542Z Executing task: Clean
2018-06-01T10:35:05.2389744Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.177.53362 for .NET Core
2018-06-01T10:35:05.2389940Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2018-06-01T10:35:05.2390085Z 
2018-06-01T10:35:05.2390243Z Build started 6/1/2018 10:35:04 AM.
2018-06-01T10:35:05.4567633Z      1>Project "D:\a\1\s\EvilCorp.Shopping.sln" on node 1 (Clean target(s)).
2018-06-01T10:35:05.4576926Z      1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
2018-06-01T10:35:05.4577117Z          Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
2018-06-01T10:35:05.4577301Z        ValidateProjects:
2018-06-01T10:35:05.4577538Z          The project "EvilCorp.Shopping.CloudFormation" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
2018-06-01T10:35:05.6568982Z      1>Project "D:\a\1\s\EvilCorp.Shopping.sln" (1) is building "D:\a\1\s\test\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining.Tests\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining.Tests.csproj" (2) on node 1 (Clean target(s)).
2018-06-01T10:35:05.6570131Z      2>_CheckForNETCoreSdkIsPreview:
2018-06-01T10:35:05.6570885Z          You are working with a preview version of the .NET Core SDK. You can define the SDK version via a global.json file in the current project. More at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869452
2018-06-01T10:35:05.6571157Z        CoreClean:
2018-06-01T10:35:05.6571366Z          Creating directory "obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\".
2018-06-01T10:35:05.6573173Z      2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300-rc1-008673\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(197,5): error : Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\test\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining.Tests\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [D:\a\1\s\test\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining.Tests\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining.Tests.csproj]
2018-06-01T10:35:05.6574793Z      2>Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\test\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining.Tests\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining.Tests.csproj" (Clean target(s)) -- FAILED.
2018-06-01T10:35:06.3974865Z      1>Project "D:\a\1\s\EvilCorp.Shopping.sln" (1) is building "D:\a\1\s\src\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining.csproj" (3) on node 2 (Clean target(s)).
2018-06-01T10:35:06.3976276Z      3>_CheckForNETCoreSdkIsPreview:
2018-06-01T10:35:06.3976868Z          You are working with a preview version of the .NET Core SDK. You can define the SDK version via a global.json file in the current project. More at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869452
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4013004Z        CoreClean:
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4013409Z          Creating directory "obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\".
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4033872Z      3>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300-rc1-008673\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(197,5): error : Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\src\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [D:\a\1\s\src\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining.csproj]
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4039865Z      3>Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\src\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining.csproj" (Clean target(s)) -- FAILED.
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4237898Z      1>Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\EvilCorp.Shopping.sln" (Clean target(s)) -- FAILED.
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4315334Z 
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4317290Z Build FAILED.
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4320946Z 
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4322792Z        "D:\a\1\s\EvilCorp.Shopping.sln" (Clean target) (1) ->
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4324451Z        "D:\a\1\s\test\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining.Tests\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining.Tests.csproj" (Clean target) (2) ->
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4324845Z        (ResolvePackageAssets target) -> 
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4325763Z          C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300-rc1-008673\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(197,5): error : Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\test\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining.Tests\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [D:\a\1\s\test\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining.Tests\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining.Tests.csproj]
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4326110Z 
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4326235Z 
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4326444Z        "D:\a\1\s\EvilCorp.Shopping.sln" (Clean target) (1) ->
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4326731Z        "D:\a\1\s\src\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining.csproj" (Clean target) (3) ->
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4327177Z          C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300-rc1-008673\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(197,5): error : Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\src\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [D:\a\1\s\src\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining.csproj]
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4327515Z 
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4327682Z     0 Warning(s)
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4327863Z     2 Error(s)
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4327987Z 
2018-06-01T10:35:06.4328151Z Time Elapsed 00:00:01.51
```

Comment: Which agent do you use? Hosted agent, Hosted VS2017 agent, or a private agent? Which agent version do you use? Do you set `clean` parameter to `true` in `Get sources` step? What error did you get when you queue builds?

Comment: We use `Hosted VS2017` agent, the `clean` is set to false but we use `dotnet clean` within our cake build scripts.

Comment: The error indicated `Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\src\EvilCorp.Shopping.BitCoinMining\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.` Did you check that?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT seems weird that I would now need to run a package restore before a clean? and this has only just started happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested on my side, Hosted VS 2017 is installed dotnet version `2.1.300-rc1-008673`:

[image]

To use other versions of dotnet sdk, you could follow the steps below:

1. Create a `global.json` file with the similar content below and check it into VSTS.

`{
   "sdk": { "version": "2.1.200" }
}`

2. Specify the `Working folder` to the location where `global.json` file is:

[image]

3. Run the command:

[image]

You could specify the dotnet sdk version you want to use in the first step, and make sure the version you want to use has existed in Hosted VS 2017.

Comment: if you do a `dotnet --info` you'll see other versions installed too... I think fixing the sdk version would fix my issue (I hope)